# remembering page state (checkboxes, show/hide panels) using cookies and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a page that has panels that can be set to visible or hidden.
There are also some checkboxes that need to be either checked or not.

I want this state to be stored in a cookie, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [jquery cookie plugin](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/) which simplifies cookie read/write operations.